# How to put condition inside <option>

Tags: reactjs

I want to check the category id.. if category.id is equal to form.catedit Iwant to make that selecteed one

```
<label for="inputEmail3" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category</label>

<select className="form-control"name="category"onChange={handleChange} id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="category">
```

```
     {tate.categories.map(category=>{
```

return(

```
  <option value={category.id}
```

{(category.id) === form.cateedit?selected:null}

```
  >{category.name}



  </option>
);

})
```

}

```
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the comparison inside of selected attribute of option tag

```
<label for="inputEmail3" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category</label>
<select className="form-control" name="category" onChange={handleChange} id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="category">
    {
        tate.categories.map(category => {
            return (
                <option value={category.id}
                    selected={category.id === form.cateedit ? true : null}
                >{category.name}
                </option>
            );

        })
    }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

use selected attribute.

```
<option selected={(category.id) === form.cateedit ? true : false}>"Option1"</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a cleaner way

```
<select className="form-control" name="category" onChange={handleChange} id="exampleFormControlSelect1" >
  {
    tate.categories.map(({id, name})=> {
      return (
        <option value={id} selected={(id === form.cateedit)  || false}>{name}</option>
      );
    })
  }
</select>
```